# New (Form) Element in Phalcon

Tags: model-view-controller, phalcon

There's a dynamic list of phone numbers, so I thought it would be a good idea to abstract this in a custom element.

There is a problem, though I don't know how to reuse existing elements, or how validation should work `($form->isValid()` should check if the phone numbers match a certain pattern, for example).

How would I be able to implement that element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex, there's an example on the official documentation:

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Validation;
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Regex;

$validation = new Validation();

$validation->add(
    'telephone',
    new Regex(
        [
            'message'    => 'The telephone is required',
            'pattern'    => '/\+44 [0-9]+/',
            'allowEmpty' => true,
        ]
    )
);
```

https://docs.phalconphp.com/hu/3.2/validation#cancelling

---

Or you can use a better regex pattern:

```
$regex = "/^(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/i";
```

https://ericholmes.ca/php-phone-number-validation-revisited/